# How to execute python scripts with a custom name without .py extension

Tags: python

Lets say I have a python script that makes an http request and prints the response code to the screen and exits.

```
# check_app_status.py

import requests

r = requests.get("https://someapp.com")

print r.status_code
```

Now i can run it by

```
$ python check_app_status.py
200
```

What do I need to set up to be able to run it like this

```
$ check-app
200
```

Comment: you have to create an entry in bash aliases

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're on a unixoid system, you just need to add a shebang line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import requests
...
```

The exact location of the python executable may vary, so you can alternatively also use the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python`, which should always work.

Then, set the executable bit (`chmod +x check-app`). Finally, if you want to be able to call it from any location, put it somewhere in your $PATH. I would recommend extending your `$PATH` with a custom directory where you put your scripts (in this case `~/bin`). To do that, put this in your `.bashrc` (or similar):

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`